# Jmeter how to capture a Guid value comming in the GET params (querystring)

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing an asp.net web aplication with jmeter. 
I'm correlating the dynamic variables but I'm having problems getting the value of the variable "Guid". 
First it cost me a lot to know where is comming, I realized that the first time is been requested by the GET method and by using an sniffer I found that is comming in the GET parameters (the querystring), the second time is comming by the GET too but is been sended by the url, like that:

```
  "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "http://srvdr.ajk.fye:27080/Art/WebP/Wep.aspx?Title=Procesar%20Instancia%20Actividad&CodigoProducto=1010102&CodigoProceso=CONST&CodigoActividad=1413&AK=12345&FechaInicio=03/02/2015%2004:01:56%20p.m.&mnu=999&Guid=64a42d6e6e2f45afb4905e82b5eddacf&SessionId=puucb42xfmgph2ggmhzrurlm044339",
```

I've trying to capture it using:

1- first a CSS/JQuery Extractor like this:

```
Reference Name:        varGuid
CSS/JQuery expression: #Guid
Attribute:             value
Match No (0 for Random): 0
Default value:
```

Didn't work...

2- Secondly I tried with a RegExp like that:

```
Reference Name:      varGuid
Regular Expression:  Guid=(.+?)&
Template:            $1$
Match No (0 for Random): 0
Default value:
```

But is not capturing anything , I don't know what else to do...
Please someone help me !

UPDATING...
error:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 268: http://srvdr.ajk.fye:27080/Art/WebP/Wep.aspx?Title=Procesar%20Instancia%20Actividad&CodigoProducto=1010102&CodigoProceso=CONST&CodigoActividad=1098&AK=673509&FechaInicio=24/01/2015%2012:58:56%20p.m.&ValidarPerfilAgencia=True&mnu=999&Guid=${varGuid}&SessionId=op5bra3jre2mrcvb10m04qy1093246
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:283)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1141)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1130)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:431)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

UPDATING with the Test Plan structure

```
Test Plan
 User Defined Variables
 HTTP Request Defaults
 HTTP Cookie Manager

 Thread Group

  Recording Controler
   Transaction Controller
     HTTP REQUEST name: 30/Art/WebL/wfmLoginD.aspx
   CSS/JQuerySessionId

   Transaction Controller
     HTTP REQUEST name: 31/Art/WebL/wfmL.aspx

   Transaction Controller
     HTTP REQUEST name: 32/Art/WebL/wfmL.aspx (In this request is comming the Guid as the GET parameters)

   RegularExpressionGuid

   Transaction Controller
     HTTP REQUEST name: 33 /Art/WebL/wfmL.aspx?Title=Procesar+Instancia+Actividad&CodigoProducto=1010102&CodigoProceso=CONST&CodigoActividad=1098&AK=${idAK}&FechaInicio=24%2f01%2f2015+12%3a58%3a56+p.m.&ValidarPerfilAgencia=True&mnu=999&Guid=${varGuid}&SessionId=${sessionid}

 Debug Sampler

View Results Tree

WorkBench
 HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
```

In The treeview result:
The request 32 is sending this error:

```
GET http://srv/Art/WebL/wfmL.aspx?Title=Procesar%20Instancia%20Actividad&CodigoProducto=1010102&CodigoProceso=CONST&CodigoActividad=1098&AK=673509&FechaInicio=24/01/2015%2012:58:56%20p.m.&ValidarPerfilAgencia=True&mnu=999&Guid=${varGuid}&SessionId=55byogbbybhrhorbebiqudrm030702

[no cookies]
```

And the response of the 32 is:

```
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 268: http://srv/Art/WebL/wfmL.aspx?Title=Procesar%20Instancia%20Actividad&CodigoProducto=1010102&CodigoProceso=CONST&CodigoActividad=1098&AK=673509&FechaInicio=24/01/2015%2012:58:56%20p.m.&ValidarPerfilAgencia=True&mnu=999&Guid=${varGuid}&SessionId=55byogbbybhrhorbebiqudrm030702
at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:283)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1141)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1130)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:431)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:258)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And in the request 33 this error, here Guid is getting the value "h" I don't understand what's happening here

```
POST http://srv/Art/WebL/wfmL.aspx?Title=Procesar+Instancia+Actividad&CodigoProducto=1010102&CodigoProceso=CONST&CodigoActividad=1098&AK=673509&FechaInicio=24%2f01%2f2015+12%3a58%3a56+p.m.&ValidarPerfilAgencia=True&mnu=999&Guid=h&SessionId=55byogbbybhrhorbebiqudrm030702

POST data:
rsmScriptManager_TSM=%3B%3BSystem.Web.Extensions%2C+Version%3D4.0.0.0%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D31bf3856ad364e35%3Aes-PE%3A509f92a1-e5fd-464f-a450-13846a6c973b%3Aea597d4b%3Ab25378d2%3BTelerik.Web.UI%2C+Version%3D2012.3.1308.40%2C+Culture%3Dneutral%2C+PublicKeyToken%3D121fae78165ba3d4%3Aes-PE%3A0c62baaa-fecc-4eb5-91ff-e3de59bf8f40%3A16e4e7cd%3Aed16cbdc%3Af7645509%3A24ee1bba%3A7165f74%3Ae330518b%3A1e771326%3A8e6f0d33%3A6a6d718d%3A8674cba1%3A7c926187%3Ab7778d6c%3Ac08e9f8a%3Aa51ee93e%3A59462f1%3A874f8ea2%3Af46195d3%3A19620875%3A490a9d4e%3Abd8f85e4%3Aa7e79140&__EVENTTARGET=btnIr&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZHo6ihSMfi3%2Bb2BIYPR7%2Bt5A2g4O&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=089A3467&__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0&__SCROLLPOSITIONY=0&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAATZZXM7aurrhLYJ0ij%2B03LaYhM0SpqGl6sQ9WQzHF7zLq7ad8Q7AL0pZvZlvE%2BM6yw6acSb565lrI%2B%2FgO9Y5T%2F8b%2BlKMjTlmm0duBT2lHLkrxDZFZg%3D&txtSalir=NO&HiddenField1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your GUID value comes as URL CSS/JQuery extractor won't help a lot.

1. Make sure that you tick "URL" in "Field to check" section
2. Make sure that you tick "Main sample and sub-samples" in "Apply to" section

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide for detailed explanation of each configuration field.

[image: Regex Scope]

Apart from these 2 points your regular expression configuration looks fine.

Comment: thanks for answering... I'm choosing those Main sample and sub-samples an URL but still not working... I'm updating the post with the error.

Comment: You'd better elaborate where do you get this `Guid` bit as we're not telepathic enough

Comment: I'm adding too, the specifics errors of the two request where is comming the Guid. In the first request is showing the literal value '${varGuid}' and in the 2nd is showing only one letter 'Guid=h'...

Comment: You need to put `RegularExpressionGuid` **as a child** of `HTTP REQUEST name: 31` (or whatever request returns this guid value)